# Highlight full width of mat row cell

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I encounter a problem when I want to highlight a row in Angular.
The HighLight works, but not on the full width.
Actual result : https://prnt.sc/u4rqjl

I don't understand why it's not on the full width..
Angular version : 10

I just see that i have a problem here ! : https://prnt.sc/u4s4tu

Html file :

```
..
...



    <ng-container matColumnDef="reportdate">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date réalisation</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.reportdate}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Action</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button *ngIf="element.status == 'KO'" mat-icon-button color="warn">
                                <mat-icon>build</mat-icon>
                            </button>
        <button *ngIf="element.status == 'OK'" mat-icon-button color="primary">
                                <mat-icon>verified</mat-icon>
                            </button>
        <button *ngIf="element.status == 'Solved'" mat-icon-button color="accent">
                                <mat-icon>verified</mat-icon>
                            </button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row.id}" (click)="highlight(row)"></mat-row>

    </mat-table>
```

Css file :

```css
.mat-row, .mat-header-row {
  min-width: 1123px;
  width:100%;
}


.mat-table {
  position:relative;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  width:100%;
  height : 100vh;
}
// The table has a scrollbar on the bottom ( because i have a lot of column)
.highlight{
  background: #00695c;
}
```

Ts file :

```js
selectedRowIndex: number = -1;
highlight(row): void {
    this.selectedRowIndex = row.id;
}
```

Comment: hi, is it possible to crate a stackblitz light demo to check this problem ?

Comment: Hello, too much things to do for this little problem, i edited my post, the problem is here : https://prnt.sc/u4s4tu
Not a problem with css color

Comment: can you edit this sample base of your problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmzfju?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is usually caused by an over-allocation of a maximum width.
This means that you have columns, which exceed 100% of the possible width!

You probably use this:

```
.mat-column-$COLUMNNAME {
  flex: 0 0 X%;
}
```

The solution is simply to delete them.
On the big screen, your table will look good
and on a small screen, your painting will have a scrollbar.

Comment: Yes perfect i was using it for each of my colum ! Now problem of width solved and color too ;)